# How to make apache beam parallel job run independently on Data flow (python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an apache beam code that reads in files in parallel from GCS and write them to different tables into Firestore. It happens that one file could contain duplicates so it would generate an error while it writes to datastore (concurrent writing). However, I am surprised that all the parallel flows fails once one file fails.

In this example, only one file contain duplicates so I am expecting to have only one error on that particular flow. However, this error seems to be propagated to another file (sometime to more files).
I am suspecting that these flows are not completely independent and not running in parallel as mentioned in the graph.

Any good interpretation on what is happening? and any hints on how to solve it?
Much appreciated

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1new.datastoreio import WriteToDatastore
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1new.types import Key
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1new.types import Entity
import hashlib
import json
from src.settings import LOCAL_SCHEMAS
import os
import logging
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

PROJECT = "test-project"


class CSVtoDict(beam.DoFn):
    """Converts line into dictionary"""

    def process(self, element, headers):
        element = re.findall(r"[^,\"]+|\"[^\"]+\"", element)
        yield dict(zip(headers, element))


class EntityWrapper(object):
    """
    Create a Cloud firestore entity from the given string.
    Namespace and project are taken from the parent key.
    """

    def __init__(self, kind, exclude_from_indexes, columns, parent_key=None):
        self._kind = kind
        self._exclude_from_indexes = exclude_from_indexes
        self._parent_key = parent_key
        self._columns = columns
        logging.info("Start entities creation")
        self._expiry_date = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=3)

    def make_entity(self, content):
        """Create entity from given string."""
        key_columns = list(set(self._columns) - set(self._exclude_from_indexes))
        entity_keys = {k: content[k] for k in key_columns}
        key = Key(
            [
                self._kind,
                hashlib.sha1(json.dumps(entity_keys).encode("utf-8")).hexdigest(),
            ],
            parent=self._parent_key,
            namespace="test-namespace",
        )
        excluded_indexes = self._exclude_from_indexes
        excluded_indexes.extend(["expiry_date"])
        entity = Entity(key, exclude_from_indexes=excluded_indexes)
        entity.set_properties({"expiry_date": self._expiry_date})
        for index_key in content.keys():
            if index_key == "rank":
                entity.set_properties({index_key: int(content[index_key])})
            else:
                entity.set_properties({index_key: str(content[index_key])})
        return entity


def dataflow():
    """
    Upload data from GCS to firestore
    """

    pipeline_options = {
        "runner": "DirectRunner",
        "job_name": "firestore-upload-{}".format(
            datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S")
        ),
    }

    options = PipelineOptions.from_dictionary(pipeline_options)
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
    for i, source in enumerate(LOCAL_SCHEMAS.keys()):
        Kind_schema = LOCAL_SCHEMAS[source]
        input_filename = Kind_schema["input_filename"]
        input_file_path = os.path.join("dummy_data", input_filename)
        columns = Kind_schema["columns"]
        kind_name = Kind_schema["kind_name"]
        exclude_from_indexes = Kind_schema["exclude_from_indexes"]
        print("upload {} to {} in firestore".format(input_file_path, kind_name))

        (
            p
            | "Reading input file_{}".format(i)
            >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input_file_path, skip_header_lines=1)
            | "Converting from csv to dict_{}".format(i)
            >> beam.ParDo(CSVtoDict(), columns)
            | "Create entities_{}".format(i)
            >> beam.Map(
                EntityWrapper(kind_name, exclude_from_indexes, columns).make_entity
            )
            | "Write entities into firestore_{}".format(i) >> WriteToDatastore(PROJECT)
        )
    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dataflow()
```

I run this code locally and on Dataflow and I am expecting the error (

> 400 A non-transactional commit may not contain multiple mutations
> affecting the same entity

) on only one flow (that correpsonds to the file containing duplicates) while it is impacting other parallel flows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkR0s.png.)

Please find also the different files i am testing:

file_1 (not containing duplicates):

```
category_id,product_id,rank,seed_product
98354900,53317,6,59596
```

file_2 (containing duplicates):
product_id,category_name,category_id,number_of_purchases,rank

```
1091056,Womts & Jackets,C_600001530,24357,1
1091052,clo,C_190118298,24357,1
1095256,Women,C_5000298,24357,1
565702,Electcals,C_50001,22304,1
555702,Home Appes,C_192851,22304,1
5655702,Gri& Fryers,C_8000535,22304,1
655702,Sma Cooking Applians,5900861776,22304,1
5417600,test,60000246,122,1
5417600,test,60000246,122,1
5417600,test,60000246,122,1
```

file_3 (not containing duplicates):

```
product_id,sub_category_name,sub_category_id,number_of_views,rank
1091056,Women's Cos & Jackets,C_601530,2357,1
5652,Grills & Frys,C_80035,22304,1
62787,Women's Drses,C_6001506,20521,1
54600,Duvet Cors,C_7003971,19990,1
```

file_4 (not containing duplicates):

```
product_id,number_of_purchases
1091056,24357
56502,22304
```

Comment: I think the error is from WriteToDatastore, is it possible that the same entity is updated?

Comment: @XQHu yes, one file contain duplicates so the same entity is updated. However, I expected that only this file fails to write to Datastore. To my surprise, this error is propagated to the other file which does not contain duplicates (please see the DAG)

Comment: @XQHu i added the files I am testing for reference

Comment: I do not know Datastore well. But if it works without any duplicates, you probably need to handle duplicates first.

Comment: @XQHu i agree, the problem is solved without duplicates. However, this example is made on purpose with one file file containing duplicates and the other not. The goal is to ensure that dataflow parallel jobs (one per each file) do not interfer with each other. Unfortunately, the error seems to be propagated to the other files

Comment: Your `create entities` step looks a bit funky. Usually, `beam.Map()` expects a function with a single input parameter (see [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/map/)), or you need to provide additional parameters explicitly. However, since you are using a class method, it has actually two input parameters (`self` and `content`). I would recommend rewriting `make_entity` to a stand-alone or at least static method. I could be completely wrong, on the other hand, I have never seen this pattern within a `beam.Map`...